# How to change placeholder color in css

Tags: css, placeholder

```html
<input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30" value="" placeholder="EMAIL"/>
<input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" size="30" value="" placeholder="PHONE"/>
```

I have two form that have id = "email".
First form placeholder color is white.
Second is black.

But, i dont know how to make this without changing email id.
The problem is my second form placeholder color is white. I cannot see this placeholder because the form background is white too.

```css
input#email:-moz-placeholder{
  color:    #999 !important;
}

input#email:-ms-input-placeholder{
  color:    #999 !important;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change an input's HTML5 placeholder color with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
#your_form input#email::-webkit-input-placeholder {color:#999;}
#your_form input#email::-moz-placeholder          {color:#999;}
#your_form input#email:-moz-placeholder           {color:#999;}
#your_form input#email:-ms-input-placeholder      {color:#999;}
```

Comment: Thanks @Igor Tkachuk . This answer fix my problem

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your question correctly, add the phone id to the same CSS rule as email. Like this:

```
input#email:-moz-placeholder,  input#phone:-moz-placeholder {
  color:    #999 !important;
}
input#email:-ms-input-placeholder, input#phone:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color:    #999 !important;
}
```

Or just remove the id and make every input with a placeholder grey.

```
input:-moz-placeholder {
  color:    #999 !important;
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color:    #999 !important;
}
```

Oh, and for your information, there are more prefixes you need to add.
Read this: [Change an HTML5 input's placeholder color with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css?rq=1)